# How to bind data to a dropdown in side a grid in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout js. I have already completed few simple examples successfully and this time trying a little bit complex one using asp.net Web Api 2 as the back end service. I use following data structure at the back end.

```
public class Customer
{


    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string NIC { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerAddress
{

    public int CustomerAddressID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerAddressTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}

public class CustomerAddressType
{
    public int CustomerAddressTypeID { get; set; }
    public string  CustomerAddressTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

A customer can have multiple address and each and every address has CustomerAddressType. I want to get one customer object from the back end and edit particular customer in the following view. Addresses can be added and deleted in the bottom grid. 
[Customer Edit View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjOZF.png)

Javascript view model

```
$(document).ready(function () {
InitiCustomerViewModel();
GetCustomer();
});


function InitiCustomerViewModel() {
    customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(customerViewModel);
    customerViewModel.CustomerID(customerID);
}

function CustomerViewModel() {
    this.CustomerID = ko.observable("");
    this.CustomerName = ko.observable("");
    this.NIC = ko.observable("");
    this.DateOfBirth = ko.observable("");
    this.Salary = ko.observable("");
    this.DepartmentID = ko.observable("");
    this.CustomerAddresses = ko.observableArray("");
    this.DepartmentList = ko.observableArray("");
    this.AddressTypeList = ko.observableArray("");
    console.info(this.AddressTypeList());
}

function GetCustomer() {
    GetDepartmentList();
    GetAddressTypeList();
    if (customerViewModel.CustomerID() > 0) {
        var jqxhr = $.get("/api/CustomerApi/GetCustomer?customerID=" + customerViewModel.CustomerID(), null, function (res) {
            LoadCustomerCompleted(res);
        },
       "json"
       ).fail(function (response) {
           alert("Request Failed");
       });
    }
}

function GetDepartmentList() {
    var jqxhr = $.get("/api/CustomerApi/GetDepartmentList", null, function (res) {
        customerViewModel.DepartmentList.removeAll();
        for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            customerViewModel.DepartmentList.push(res[i]);
        }
    },
     "json"
     ).fail(function (response) {
         alert("Request Failed");
     });
}

function GetAddressTypeList() {
    var jqxhr = $.get("/api/CustomerApi/GetAddressTypeList", null, function (responce) {
        customerViewModel.AddressTypeList.removeAll();
        for (i = 0; i < responce.length; i++) {

            customerViewModel.AddressTypeList.push(responce[i]);
        }
    },
     "json"
     ).fail(function (response) {
         alert("Request Failed");
     });
}


function LoadCustomerCompleted(response) {
    customerViewModel.CustomerID(response.CustomerID);
    customerViewModel.CustomerName(response.CustomerName);
    customerViewModel.NIC(response.NIC);
    customerViewModel.Salary(response.Salary);
    customerViewModel.DepartmentID(response.DepartmentID);
    customerViewModel.DateOfBirth(response.DateOfBirth);
    customerViewModel.CustomerAddresses.removeAll();
    for (i = 0; i < response.CustomerAddresses.length; i++) {
        customerViewModel.CustomerAddresses.push(response.CustomerAddresses[i]);
    }

}
```

HTML View

```
@model KnockoutJSWithWebAPI.Models.Customer

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CustomerMaintanance</h2>

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Customer</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: CustomerName" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NIC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: NIC" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: DateOfBirth" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Salary" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: DepartmentList, optionsText: 'DepartmentName', optionsValue:'DepartmentID', value: DepartmentID, optionsCaption: '--Select a Department--'"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Adrress Type</td>
                        <td>Address</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: CustomerAddresses">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.AddressTypeList, optionsText: $root.AddressTypeList. CustomerAddressTypeName,  value: $data.CustomerAddressTypeID, optionsCaption: '--Select Address Type--'"></select>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="text: Address"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Address" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var customerID = "@Model.CustomerID";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/ViewModels/CustomerMaintanance.js")">
</script>
```

All the fields are binding correctly except the AddressType drop down in the grid. It shows [object,object] instead of CustomerAddressTypeName.

[Address type Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kaGX.png)

Please help me to find out the issue in my application.

Answer (score 1):

the "optionsText" binding on your dropdown takes a string for the name of the property that contains the display text. It should probably read "optionsText: 'CustomerAddressTypeName'" instead of "optionsText: $root.AddressTypeList. CustomerAddressTypeName"

Comment: I tried with "CustomerAddressTypeName" as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well I don't actually see that property on your JavaScript model so either you need to share the code where it's located or it doesn't exist and you need to add it.